# Format of AWS SQS queue url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Newbie query on format of SQS queue url :

Format goes like this :

```
aws-sqs://<name>?amazonSQSClient=#amazonSQSClient&param1=value1&param2=value2.
```

My question is what does amazonSQSClient parameter refer to since it has a # in the value.
Could not find the info in Amazon docs.

Comment: Where did you get this URL? The documentation shows an example as: `https://queue.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyQueue`

Comment: This is specific to Camel SQS integration where a camel route is defined starting or ending to an SQS queue. https://blog.christianposta.com/camel/jms-style-selectors-on-amazon-sqs-with-apache-camel/

Answer (score 0):

#amazonSQSClient refers to a bean of the same name which is of type AmazonSQS - interface for accessing amazon SQS. So # denotes bean name.